# How do I hash an element in a registration form in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I tried looking around and I couldn't find anything. I want to hash the password on the registration page before it inserts into the database. I did some searching, and I found some hash related things for `addValidator()`, but from my understanding, that is to validate an element, but I actually need to transform an element before inserting in the the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the hash in the controller, before you send the data to the model and after the form validation. Besides, this task should not be achieved by a validator and this is why you cannot find anyone who fits your need. Indeed it should be done by a filter. Anyway, there's no filter which achieve this goal too.

To hash the password, hence, you can use any built-in hash function of php as `hash`, `md5`, `sha1`.

Comment: Oh, this way, I don't know have to do anything to the form. Okay, fair enough. Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

In conjunction with AurelioDeRosa's answer please read [PHP's advice on hashing passwords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash).    In short you shouldn't use `hash`, `md5` or `sha1` to hash passwords.  It is suggested that you use the built in `crypt` function with the `Blowfish` algorithm.  See the link for an explanation.